# How to create Heat map for swing applications?

Tags: java, heatmap

I'm trying to build a tool that will locate a component on a Swing application (eg a button or text field) and 'highlight it'. i was thinking about using the idea of [heat maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) for highlighting.

Has anyone ever used such a thing and maybe can indicate how they can be generated for this idea because I'm not finding a lot of relevant information relating to this.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless I missed something from your question, this should be pretty easy. One can set the background color of almost all Swing components. For Example, all sub-classes of `javax.swing.JComponent` have a `setBackground()` method on them.

The second step is to actually assign a color. For that, you need to know the min, max and the observed value. If we you were to do a simple heatmap e.g. white to red, then you just need to determine the amount of Red component in an RGB `Color` specification. This can be done with the formula:

```
int red = ((value-min)/(max-min))*255;
Color color = new Color(red, 255, 255)
```

You then assign `color` as the background for your button of text field.

Comment: This is a good suggestion as well. You can do this instead of drawing an overlay (see my response below)

Comment: thanks a lot for this comment... the formula for the colour was so helpful... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion does not rely on Heatmaps but might suite your needs. 
Most Swing UI components inherit from JComponent which has :
 - A `getLocation` method that returns the location of the component on the parent frame
 - A `getSize` method that returns the size of the component
You can add a method to your frame that looks up a component given its location on the frame (a simple collision detection algorithm will help)

Once you find that component you can draw a semi transparent overlay of any size you want (a rectangle or any other shape) on that location using 2D Graphics (see [example](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java%3aTutorials%3aGraphics)). 
This way you can outline any component on your main frame given its location.
I hope this helps.